# Data not being displayed in form when fetching values from database

Tags: mysql

I am wanting to put the values I have fetched from my database through a query into my HTML form's drop down menu. However, the drop down menu in my form shows blank values, and I am not sure if it is to do with the syntax of my code or the query itself.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(acd.Room_No, SPACE(1), acd.Band, SPACE(1), acd.Total_Cost, SPACE(1), ad.Street) as info FROM accommodation_details as acd 
 INNER JOIN Address as ad
 WHERE ad.Address_ID = acd.Address_ID AND acd.Availability = "Y";
```

on running this query in get this output:

```
+-------------------------------+
| info                          |
+-------------------------------+
| 1D A 6950 Basketball Lane     |
| 2C B 7000 ONCE Housing        |
| 2D B 7000 ONCE Housing        |
| 2E B 7000 ONCE Housing        |
| 3B C 7000 Petits Filous Road  |
| 3D C 7000 Petits Filous Road  |
| 3E C 7000 Petits Filous Road  |
| 4B D 7000 Sanpei Heights      |
| 4C D 7000 Sanpei Heights      |
| 4E D 7000 Sanpei Heights      |
| 14A D 6900 Golden Gate Towers |
| F7 B 4530 Hudson River        |
| F8 B 4530 Sora Close          |
+-------------------------------+
```

in which the query is shown to be working, now when **I try to put these values into my HTML form drop down box** using PHP through this code:

```
    <label for = "rooms_avail">Select a room: </label>
    <select name = "rooms_avail" id = "rooms_avail" style="width: 300px;">
        <option>Select</option>
        <?php
             $query = 'SELECT CONCAT(acd.Room_No, SPACE(1), acd.Band, SPACE(1), acd.Total_Cost, SPACE(1), 
ad.Street) FROM accommodation_details as acd 
             INNER JOIN Address as ad WHERE ad.Address_ID = acd.Address_ID AND acd.Availability = "Y";';
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<option>'.$row["acd.Room_No"].'</option>'; 
                echo '<option>'.$row["acd.Band"].'</option>';
                echo '<option>'.$row["acd.Total_Cost"].'</option>';
                echo '<option>'.$row["Street"].'</option>';
            }
            ?>
    </select>
```

I get the following output in my form:
[image]

any advise on how i can get around this issue?
Also sorry if I posted in the wrong forum, I am not sure if this is to do with my query (through the database hence on the db forum).

Comment: You are expecting 13 * 4 options?  Even if it worked, I don't think you want it laid out that way.  Toss the `acd.`.  What is `SPACE(1)`?

Comment: SPACE(1) adds a space between each element in the row

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. I was echoing each field of my query rather than echoing the id of the concatenated version of the row.

My previous code (which was echoing each id of each fields)

```
        echo '<option>'.$row["acd.Room_No"].'</option>'; 
        echo '<option>'.$row["acd.Band"].'</option>';
        echo '<option>'.$row["acd.Total_Cost"].'</option>';
        echo '<option>'.$row["Street"].'</option>';
```

I changed my code to:

```
         $query = 'SELECT CONCAT(acd.Room_No, SPACE(1), acd.Band, SPACE(1), acd.Total_Cost, SPACE(1), ad.Street) as info FROM accommodation_details as acd 
         INNER JOIN Address as ad WHERE ad.Address_ID = acd.Address_ID AND acd.Availability = "Y";';
```

where I used `as info` in the query (to name the whole row) and instead echoed the name used to recognize each row (with concatenated fields):

```
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option>'.$row["info"].'</option>';
```

And now displays each row in info in the drop down box